# WooCommerce: Add product descriptions underneath the items in single item page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display the product description for each (variation) item right underneath its respective thumbnail. So when I click each thumbnail and the main image slides into view, it would have its description written under it as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

I think this is the code to display the description:

```
<?php echo $value[‘variation_description’];?>
```

But which template do I have to edit? I browsed through the WooCommerce folder but couldn't find the template I needed.

Edit: I think `product-image.php` is the template I need to edit but where would I insert the line above?

```
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $wrapper_classes ) ) ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
        <?php
        if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
            $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
        } else {
            $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
            $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src( 'woocommerce_single' ) ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        ?>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this function [created by John Beales](https://github.com/jbeales/woo-gallery-captions/blob/master/woo-gallery-captions.php). It approaches the problem in a different way by displaying the title of the image (set in media settings). Works great.

```
function gcw_insert_captions( $html, $attachment_id ) {
    $captions = '';
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id );
    if( !empty( $title ) ) {
        $captions .= '<h5>' . esc_html( $title ) . '</h5>';
    }
    $description = get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id );
    if( !empty( $description ) ) {
        $captions .= '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
    }
    if( !empty( $captions ) ) {
        $captions = '<div class="gcw-caption">' . $captions . '</div>';

        $html = preg_replace('~<\/div>$~', $captions . '</div>', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'gcw_insert_captions', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a hook which can help you to add description under item image directly but you can add under thumbnails. using this hook

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'content_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );

    function content_add_below_prod_gallery() {
       echo 'Hello';
    }
```

otherwise you can edit product-image.php file which you can find in
woocommerce/templates/single-productproduct-image.php

Note: This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php.

Comment: I don't think that code will display the description for each variation item, right? I was looking at the product-image.php template but couldn't figure out where to insert my code.

Comment: there are two places where you can check simple add a dummy div and can test.
URL: http://prntscr.com/np2he6